# integer value read from System.in is not the value typed

Tags: java

I am a newbie to Java, and as an exercise wanted to WAP a simple program to print required no. of '*' characters according to the user. But somehow, the output of this code always remains similar:

```
package stars;

public class Stars {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int no_stars=0;

        try {

            System.out.print("Enter the number of stars:");
            no_stars = (int)System.in.read();

        } catch ( Exception e)    {

            System.out.println("Error! Invalid argument!");
            System.out.println();

        } 

    printstars(no_stars);

    }
    public static void printstars(int n){
        int i;
        for(i=0;i<=n;i++)
        {    
             System.out.println('*');
        }

    }


}
```

If I replace '*' with i, I can see that it loops upto 50/52/54, even though i run the loop no_stars times.

What seems to be the problem here?

Comment: What is your expected output and currently what the output look like?

Comment: do a System.out.println(n); before the loop

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you are reading ASCII code of the character from input here:

```
no_stars = (int)System.in.read();
```

It should be

```
no_stars = Integer.parseInt(Console.readLine());
```

Answer (score 12):

You need to parse the number received from `System.in.read()` or alternatively read it as an integer, currently you just cast it, so if you enter 5, it passes 0x35 times (which is the value of the character '5')

You can do, for example:

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner( System.in );
printstars( scan.nextInt() );
```

Comment: Thats a great answer... I am new to this.. :)

Comment: Thankyou, this worked. But I still dont understand that why was I getting 50,52 or 54 stars? Even if the system.in.read() reads only the first character, i have entered ints like 7, 10, 86, 3, etc. and gotten the same ouput among {50,53,54}. Could you explain this?

Comment: '7' has the value of 0x37 which is 55. which is close enough (considering you gave examples and not actual values).

Answer (score 1):

```
no_stars = (int)System.in.read();
```

This is using the ASCII value of whatever character the user enters. Try this instead:

```
no_stars = System.in.read() - '0';
```

Or, remove the `no_stars` variable all together,

```
printstars(System.in.read() - '0');
```

---

Also, in your `for`-loop, the condition should be `i < n`, in order to perform the correct number of iterations. And there's no need to declare `i` outside of the loop, you can just do `for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)`.

Comment: thanks, but still i would be stuck with the one byte of input. I think i'll be using the scanner class mostly.

Answer (score 1):

There are two mistakes in your code.

---

**First**

```
System.in.read()
```

Is reading a byte, not a integer, so, it is parsing the integer and getting the first byte of it.

---

**Second**

```
for (i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
```

will print always one star more than requested. 
So, it should be changed to

```
for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
```

---

Suggestion: You could use Scanner to read your integer, for example

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
no_stars = scanner.nextInt();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the corrected program for you: (the main problem was this line //no_stars = (int)System.in.read();)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int no_stars=0;
    try{
        System.out.print("Enter the number of stars:");
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        String name=sc.nextLine();
        no_stars = Integer.parseInt(name);
        //no_stars = (int)System.in.read();
    }
    catch ( Exception e)    {
        System.out.println("Error! Invalid argument!");
        System.out.println();
    } 
    printstars(no_stars);
}
public static void printstars(int n)
{System.out.println(n);
int i;
for(i=0;i<=n;i++)
{    
    System.out.println('*');
}
}
```